# Is it possible to get the address of a Reference variable in java

Tags: java, string

Consider `String message = "World" and String message2 = "World"`

As per string immutability there will be only one string in memory i.e. "World".

So Both message and message2 will point to the same string in the memory.

Is there a way to verify this in Java. Some way to get the address of reference variable in java to actually verify that they indeed are same?

Comment: message == message2

Answer (score 2):

String *reference* comparison would be `message == message2` instead of normal value comparison `message.equals(message2)`.

As String is a final class one cannot get the `Object.toString()` which would give a string representation of the object "address" in the form class + '@' + hex address.

Comment: That 'address' that Object's toString returns can be retrieved for any object using `System.identityHashCode(obj)` - however, this isn't really an address, and not even guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I even forgot. I would not like to see this used, so I will not add it to the answer. BTW an IDE debugger will often number its objects like 1983, which is more useful.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no, there isn't a way to get the address<sup>1</sup>. But there are 2 things that can get real close.

1. THe `==` operator checks reference identity in java, not equality. Unless the left and right hand side are primitives, then 'reference identity' has no meaning, and it does test for equality. In other words, `a == b` checks that a and b are pointing at the same object; not that the objects they are pointing to are considered equal. Let's try it!

```
String x = new String("a");
String y = new String("a");
System.out.println(x == y); // prints false
System.out.println(x.equals(y)); // prints true
```

turns out `"a" == "a"` *is* true, because any constants mentioned in source files get 'optimized', more or less: Only one string object is made, and then any mention of it results in a reference to the one constant made.

Note that this doesn't hold universally: In the above example, we have 2 string objects that  both have the value "a", but are not `==` equal, because there is no rule that states that there can only be one `"a"` in the entire VM.

2. `System.identityHashCode(x)` returns the so-called system hashcode of x: It isn't quite the memory address, but pretty close to it: It hashes the reference, effectively. It is theoretically possible to have 2 objects such that: `System.identityHashCode(a) == System.identityHashCode(b) && a != b`, but this is extremely hard to actually have happen. Certainly any 2 objects that do not have the same identity hashcode are guaranteed to 'be in different places in memory', so to speak: They are not the same object. The reverse is 99.99999% of the time also true, but not quite 100% true (trivial proof: a 64-bit VM can have more than 4 billion objects, but there are only 4 billion hashcodes. pigeonhole principle applies, QED).

[1] With `com.misc.Unsafe` you can get even closer, but even that isn't guaranteed to be the physical RAM address either, IIRC.